# Prevent user to click on browsers back button Angular2

Tags: browser, navigation, angular2-routing

I am working with Angular 2 JS with Typescript. I have a requirement where I don't want to click/navigate to previous page via Browsers back button.

So how we can disable or prevent user to click or move to previous page via browser.

I have tried some example which are available over internet but those are not working properly. Like -

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on page load, it will stop user on navigating back from page on which it placed.

put the code as it is in index.html page of the angular

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    function changeHashOnLoad() {
        window.location.href += "#";
        setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50");
    }

    function changeHashAgain() 
    {          
        window.location.href += "1";
    }

    var storedHash = window.location.hash;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
            window.location.hash = storedHash;
        }
    }, 50);

    </script>
```

Comment: #Aman, this need to put on Index page or on which page from where I want to prevent back button navigation ?